# Can I create a new partition my hard drive after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu on a new hard drive.  I did not perform any partitioning operations during installation.  After the installation and upgrade, I tried to partition the drive in which Ubuntu was installed.

- Partition: `/dev/sda2`
- File System: ext4
- Mount Point: `/`

I am not able to create another partition from this one.  Is it possible to do it or should I have to live with one BIG partition?

The option to resize this partition is greyed out.

What happens if I try to unmount this partition?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this using `fdisk` command
you can do major operation with disk-drive

For a step-by-step guide refer to this link: [How to use fdisk to manage partitions on Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the link, which will help you to resize the drive partition and to create an extended partition. From the resized partition you can create a primary or an extended partition:

- [**HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition** | Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to shrink the **running** *system partition of Ubuntu*.

*That is like to ask a surgeon to give himself a double bypass...*  ;-)

Boot the Ubuntu Live CD or the [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and *then* repartition!